# Efficient implementation of a certain operation on numpy arrays

Tags: numpy, performance, memory, vectorization

Consider the following code block

```
N = 28 * 28
X = rng.randn(10000, N)
n_groups = group_size = 28
Q = X[:10]
Z = X[:, None] * Q[None]  # line 4: multiply every row of Q by every row of X
Z = Z.reshape((len(X), len(Q), n_groups, group_size)).mean(axis=3)
```

**Question.** How to re-implement the above code snippet to output the same result for Z, but without the costly (memory-wise, etc.) operation on line 4 ?

My hope is that this is possible via some kind of native tensor or multi-dimensional dot product.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you call this 'a setting operation'?  It's a common broadcasted multiply followed by reduction (via mean).  Often if the intermediate array is too large, it's more efficient to iterate on the smallest dimension.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Sorry for the typo, I meant "certain".

Comment: sorry for the omission, N = 784 in that example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fast standard way of doing this in Numpy is to use **`einsum`**:

```py
X2 = X.reshape(len(X), n_groups, group_size)
Q2 = Q.reshape(len(Q), n_groups, group_size)
Z = np.einsum('ikl,jkl->ijk', X2, Q2, optimize=True) / group_size
```

This is not only significantly faster but also more memory efficient since there is no *temporary array* to create. Note that `einsum` is not optimal in this case because of the rather small last dimension and a sequential execution. One can write an optimized parallel Numba/Cython code for better performance if this is not fast enough.

Note that the `/ group_size` can be applied on `Q2` rather than the result of `np.einsum` for even better performance (since `Q2` is smaller and this is mathematically equivalent).

---

### Benchmark

Here are results on my i5-9600KF processor with Numpy 1.24.3:

```
Initial implementation:  167 ms
Reinderien's solution:    70 ms
Naive einsum:             53 ms
Optimized einsum:         49 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

Jérôme Richard's fundamental insight, that this is a multiply-and-sum followed by a division, is correct, and likely to be the fastest without bypassing Numpy.

`einsum` is a highly-generalized matrix product function and what you have is "only" a standard matrix product over the last two dimensions. For illustration, I show that this is equivalent to the following:

```py
import time

import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng

n_groups = group_size = 28
N = n_groups * group_size
rng = default_rng(seed=0)
X = rng.random((10_000, N))
Q = X[:10, :]

a = time.perf_counter()

xx, qq = np.broadcast_arrays(
    X.reshape((len(X), 1, -1)),
    Q.reshape((1, len(Q), -1)),
)

Z = (
    xx.reshape((len(X), len(Q), n_groups, 1, group_size)) @
    qq.reshape((len(X), len(Q), n_groups, group_size, 1))
)[...,0,0] / n_groups

b = time.perf_counter()
print(b - a)
```

Comment: `einsum` uses the BLAS functions were possible, just like `matmul/@`.

Comment: Generally performance cannot be compared that way between machine (because overheads are non-linear and the CPUs/RAM does does not behave the same). In fact, your code takes 70 ms on my machine, so it is slower than `einsum`.

Comment: tyvm; edited for performance clarity